# Count how many times a function is called in a time

Tags: c++

I need a way to check how many times a function is called in a second. I need to see in 1 second how many times it gets called. How I can do that? I saw tricks about how many times is called.. what I need is how many times is called in 1 second or 5 second

I have an online game, and cheaters did damage speed hacks... The function is called  `CCharacter::Attack`, I need to count how many times per second a normal player can call this function.. based on his character status. And the count how many times per second a hacker call `::Attack`

Comment: Seems to me like a XY Problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This question needs more context. How is the function called? Can you modify it?

Comment: I have an online games, and checaters did damage speed hacks... The function is called  CCharacter::Attack , i need count how many times per second a normal player can call this function.. based on his character status.. And the count how many times per second an hacker call ::Attack

Comment: Online games should always validate all player actions on the server side. Assume the client might be buggy, hacked, or whatever, and make sure any input at all won't break server logic or allow player actions that should not be possible. Having some rules in the client code is helpful, but the server should never count on them.

Comment: If you had (helped to) make an online game, I would suspect that you already know how to setup a counter function in the server and verify it at a normal interval - say every 30 frames of gameplay.

Answer (score 1):

If N runs of your func take K seconds, you can calculate "number of time func is called in 1 second" by dividing `result=N/K` or in 5 sec `result5 = 5*N/K`

Answer (score 0):

You would need two things:

1. A counter where the function can count how often it was called
2. A timer, which calls another function every second to read out this counter and store the result somewhere else and reset the counter for the next time interval.

Good luck implementing this. Please post the result, this might be very interesting for other people, too!